# ODI Data Error - ORABPEL-15235

Tags: xml, json, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to convert from a json file then load into an oracle database

However, when I try and process a number that is >10 characters long, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: class java.sql.SQLException
oracle.odi.jdbc.driver.xml.io.exception.PipelineStageException: ORABPEL- 15235

Translation Failure.
Failed to translate JSON to XML. class java.sql.SQLDataException said data exception: numeric value out of range
The incoming data does not conform to the NXSD schema. Please correct the problem.
```

The XSD file I am using is structured like:

```
<xsd:element name="Root-Element">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="recordId" type="xsd:long"/>
```

And the json file that I am trying to read from is:

```
{
    "recordId" : "5931231231123"
}
```

The only documentation I have found on the xsd types is:     http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#long

The file is processed correctly if the number is 10 or less characters, or if I change the element type to xsd:string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when reverse engineering the nXSD file, ODI created attributes for all of the fields in the model, and set the default limit to 10 characters